# Storing secret keys in php files

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, security

I am using Amazon web services in my php application. Is it safe to store the secret aws access tokens in a config.php file that are linked to my php web service?

I have been unable to download the file to look at the content, but isn't it possible to use a packet sniffer or something and be able to read the key and pass phrase?

I know Amazon recommends using a token vending machine to create temporary credentials, instead of using the aws creds directly, but we are hoping to be able to skip implementing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless your config.php file will output the tokens when it is run, you should be safe. To take extra precaution, you could place the config.php file below the root directory of your website so that the user isn't even able to try to run that file.

Your php is being executed on the server, and as long as no output is being sent to the client that contains the tokens, the contents of that file will never be sent to the client. Therefore, they would have no way of reading the file because the contents never leave the server, just the output from running the script.

Answer (score 4):

In terms of "downloading the PHP file", Apache would prevent that from happening but you should definitely store the PHP file outside of the document root so it isn't accessible to the web in the first place (and require() it on the server side if needed).

In terms of "packet sniffing", secure connections prevent that from happening. Just make sure you're using HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

No. It's not possible as the script runs on the server side only, before delivering the content to the client.

The only possible breach is if someone hacked into the server itself, and stole the file from the file system.

Comment: Most successful attacks are on the server.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to above recommendations (to store your configs outside of public directory of the website) it's a good technique to encrypt your passwords/secrets rather than store them as plain text anywhere (especially when using non-php files for storing passwords such as `.env` or `*.yml` etc.). It's quite easy to expose vulnerable data by misconfiguration of webserver, commiting to Github etc.

More reading on this: https://blog.fortrabbit.com/how-to-keep-a-secret

Comment: Where would you securely save the encryption key?

Comment: @zaph It's not possible to store the encryption key absolutely securely as it's stored in the same codebase (obviously not in the same config file). This technique is more obfuscation rather than real encryption but, as I said, can prevent secrets from easy exposing in case of server misconfiguration etc.